# Call UICollectionViewController as a object

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am new to `UICollectionView`, I know how to build a `UICollectionViewController`, But as my `ViewController.m` is becoming clumsy, I want to move `UICollectionViewContoller` in to different class and call it from view controller and connect it to `IBOutlet` in `UIViewController`

some thing like

```
@interface simpleCollectionView : UICollectionView
```

Call this object in to View controller.

Answer (score 0):

You should need to study `Design Patterns`
 For iOS
here is an example 
http://www.raywenderlich.com/46988/ios-design-patterns 
Like MVC for Example: You are using using `UICollectionViewController`
the `Model` and `View` can be extended from `NSObject` classes ..

Answer (score 0):

You may subclass UICollectionView as SimpleCollectionView, and declare your ViewController to extend SimpleCollectionView (@interface MyViewController : SimpleCollectionView).

I suspect, however, that what you're actually looking for is a container View Controller which would allow you to embed a view controller inside an existing view.